# Why does sh interpret these commands differently to zsh?

Tags: shell, sh, posix, zsh

Context: I am trying to get the names of fonts installed on my Linux machine. The name is between two colons. When I run this script using zsh, it works. When I switch to sh it breaks. It probably deletes \n characters, because the output is all one line.

```
cmd="$(fc-list)"
names="$(echo $cmd | grep -oP "(?<=: ).*?(?=:)")"
echo $names
```

Which command causes the issues? Is it not POSIX compliant?

Comment: Try `echo "$names"`...

Comment: The behavior of `zsh` here is totally unacceptable!  Yet another reason to avoid `echo` completely.

Comment: @WilliamPursell It has nothing to do with `echo`, and everything to do with how `zsh` expands unquoted words. (You can get the `sh` behavior with `setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT`).

Comment: And with `${=cmd}` whether it's quoted or not and whether or not `SH_WORD_SPLIT` is set or not. And `${==cmd}` to always get default `zsh` behavior again regardless of quotes and `SH_WORD_SPLIT`. `zsh` has an overwhelming number of options.

Answer (score 5):

> Why does sh interpret these commands differently to zsh?

Because they are different shell the rules are different.

> Which command causes the issues?

```
echo $cmd
```

and

```
echo $names
```

> Is it not POSIX compliant?

The code, by itself, is valid POSIX code. The behavior of zsh shell that doesn't do word splitting is not compliant with POSIX.

In POSIX shell unquoted expansions undergo word splitting. Because default IFS is space tab and newline, these characters are erased when creating words from the result of expansion and passed as separate words to `echo` which outputs them on one line. To disable word splitting (and filename expansion), you need to quote the expansion. Also prefer `printf` to `echo`.

```
cmd="$(fc-list)"
names="$(printf "%s\n" "$cmd" | grep -oP "(?<=: ).*?(?=:)")" 
printf "%s\n" "$names"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the claim that it is POSIX compliant.  The fact that the builtin echo from zsh does not do the field splitting but prints the newlines seems to be totally non-compliant.

Comment: @William Pursell This has been fixed.